# How to use ReportViewer 2012 in Visual Studio 2013 (WinForms/Wpf)

Tags: reportviewer, report-viewer2012

I would like to upgrade a project which uses RDLC to create reports. The solution uses Report Viewer 2010SP1.
I installed successfully the report viewer 2012 runtime, however the component does not appear in the add references windows of visual studio.
I also checked the NuGet-Packages and there I found a “Report Viewer”-package 11, but while installing this version, only the web-component but not the WinForms-component has been installed.

On the web I have seen some workarounds changing the registry, but is it really necessary to manually change the registry to have this done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way, probably not the best, is selecting the component directly with the "browse"-option.

In the “Add Reference” dialog, browse to “\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ReportViewer” and select there the component "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll"

Comment: Unfortunate it's such a hack solution.